# Improving performance of Core Animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-animation, core-graphics

I have built a UI where the majority of what's on screen is put there using CALayer's. The layers are fairly simple in terms of their setup; the majority have an image set as their contents and a couple have a shadow. There are also some `CALayer` derivatives such as `CATextLayer` and `CAGradientLayer`. At any one time there is about 18 layers on screen. The contents of 11 layers change frequently (*but not to represent an animation*), and the same 11 can be scrolled to the left or the right as they are embedded in a `UIScrollView`.

I have noticed that performance is a little sluggish on both my 3GS and 4 so I am looking for ways to tune what I have to hopefully improve performance somewhat.

I have set `rasterizationScale` to the appropriate scale depending on the device and have set `shouldRasterize` to `YES`.

The images are passed to the layers in the following way ...

`someLayer.contents = (id)someUIImage.CGImage`

Is there anything else I can do to improved the overall performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to use the profiling tools available to you to figure out exactly what is slowing you down.

This previous answer says it better than I could:
[iOS / Core-Animation: Performance tuning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003616/ios-core-animation-performance-tuning)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CATiledLayer instead of a CALayer, which will render the images in a separate thread and will definitely improve your performance...

Comment: I had pondered this but how would I handle user interaction? The layers in the `UIScrollView` are wrapped inside `UIView`s so that I can interact with them. As far as I'm aware this isn't possible using `CATiledLayer`.